# not enough space for environment appears when executing ".exe" file

Tags: memory, windows-7, console, dos, clipper

I am trying to use an application called `CLUT.exe` which is an old application for `MS-DOS` that can be used to reindex `NTX` files for `DBF` databases.

(This is not the main topic, but I am just writing this if someone wants to test the app and don't trust at all about the content).

The problem starts when trying to run the command line version through console (`cmd.exe`)  and this error appears:

```
C:\>CLUT.exe [arg1] [arg2] [arg3]

run-time error R6009
- not enough space for environment
```

So, according to what I've searched, this could be a possible solution:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;230205

but it doesn't work and every alternative that I found to solve this over the internet is the same.

Another alternative could be to make **right-click** in the **.exe** file, go to **Properties** then **Memory** tab and increase the **Initial environment memory** from **Auto** to the **max value** but it doesn't work too.

---

Well, I am stuck and no "possible" solution is working for me. If someone is interested, knows more about this issue and want to test, you can download the application from here *(click "Free Download" green button)*:

http://www.filebasket.com/free/Development-Clipper-programming-language/clut-exe/13996.html

or directly from my DropBox:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15208254/stackoverflow/clut_214.rar

---

Just to know, I am using `Windows 7` and the `CLUT.exe` application is a `Clipper` based app (old programming language) that may run under windows console (`cmd.exe`).

Comment: I know this is not a 100% software development topic but If someone wants to transfer this to other site, there is no problem at all. I just put this because I am working now on a C# project in which I need to run this file in a hidden process, If this is not correct please correct it, thanks.

Comment: You're not using 64-bit Win'7, are you?   Have you tried something like [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com)?

Comment: @PM77-1 I tried `DosBox` but when executing `CLUT.exe`, the console get stuck and nothing happens. Just to know I am using 32-bit Win 7.

Comment: Have you tried actually reducing the size of the environment used before calling the program?  For example, if your **PATH** is huge then save it, define only what's needed for CLUT, run it it, and then restore.

Comment: Another bit of information: on Win 7 the file that controls 16-bit processes is **CONFIG.NT** (not CONFIG.SYS).

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, I already know that, but you can edit `config.nt` or run `sysedit` and then edit `config.sys` (both cases don't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia does mention other [dos emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDOS_emulators) but, oddly, doesn't mention [BOCHS](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/).

Reindexing NTX files is not a difficult thing to do, and can be done with tools other than CLUT. For example, many of the utilities listed on this part of [Download32](http://www.download32.com/ntx-reindex-software.html) could be used. Otherwise, you could write your own using [Harbour Project](http://harbour.github.io/) or [xHarbour](http://www.xharbour.org/). Or contact me off list and I'll cook up something in Clipper 5.3.

**LATER**

If I read the README correctly for CLUT, it's a replacement for the DBU utility that comes with Clipper 5.x. I can supply you with a build of that if you're unsuccessful with other approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention! Just to know, I got an alternative (after a lot of research) to solve this and used another `.exe` called `indexman` that does the same as `CLUT`. Well, I will really appreciate if you can share with me the `DBU` utility. I think it's hard to find it and will be good to have it (If you still got it).

Comment: That's source and binary. If you have any problems with the binary, please let me know. http://sdrv.ms/12h94hT